# In AsyncTask server's data is not getting on first time in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to get data from server using `AsyncTask`, on first time result not showing, but its working from second time. I seen so many examples but none of them working for me. please see my code below

```
private void event_load_data_from_server(int id){


        AsyncTask<Integer,Void,Void> task = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Integer... integers) {

                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                        .url("http://api.zesteve.com/posteventlist.php?city="+ucl+"&eveid="+eveid+"&id="+integers[0])
                        .build();
                try {
                    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

                    for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){

                        JSONObject object =array.getJSONObject(i);

                        if(object.has("name")){
                            pname=object.getString("name");
                        }else{
                            pname="";
                        }
                        if(object.has("timestamp")){
                            timestamp =object.getString("timestamp");
                        }else{
                            timestamp="";
                        }
                        if(object.has("id")){
                            eveid=object.getInt("id");
                        }else {
                            eveid=0;
                        }
                        if(object.has("address")){
                            address=object.getString("address");
                        }else {
                            address="";
                        }
                        if(object.has("thumbnail")){
                            thumbnail=object.getString("thumbnail");
                        }else {
                            thumbnail="";
                        }

                        EventPost events = new EventPost(pname, eveid, thumbnail,address,timestamp);

                        eventPostList.add(events);
                    }

                }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    System.out.println("End of Catagory");
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute(){
                super.onPreExecute();
                progressDialog.setMessage("Events Loading Wait...");
                showDialog();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                hideDialog();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
        task.execute(id);

    }
```

Comment: i would have respect you. if you give me the reason for down vote. there is always an option for comment.

Comment: You should initialise and build your `OkHttpClient` outside `doInBackground`. Also return your response in `onPostExecute`

Comment: can you please answer.

Comment: Have a look at my answer

Comment: @AseshaGeorge Have you debug what you get for first time?

Comment: i don't see any errors or warnings.

Comment: @AseshaGeorge Ok. I am posting answer and try that.

Comment: @AseshaGeorge I think your question is not proper, that's why you got down-vote (not by me). See your question's peer review in comment.

Comment: try invoking this method in `onCreate()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Whenever you want to use **`onPostExecute()`** method in AsyncTask, just make sure use **String** or other type instead of Void as **result parameter** of **`AsyncTask<x, y, String>`** where x,y are any data type(Integer,String,etc..).

Therefore, make changes in code as per below:

1. Make both AsyncTask<...> like this `AsyncTask<Integer,Void,String>`
2. Change return type of `doInBackground` from `Void` to `String`
3. Change `return null;` with `return "";` at last line in `doInBackground`.
4. Change `onPostExecute(Void aVoid)`  to  `onPostExecute(String s)` for override function of onpostexecute.

Then try it.

Comment: Nitin i tied your solution, i dont see any change. not getting data on first time

Comment: @AseshaGeorge Then what you got in response for first time?

Comment: i am using the same code in MainActivity its working fine, but its not working in different Activity

Comment: @AseshaGeorge Whenever we use Void as result parameter it will not go to onPostExecute method. I have checked that with implementing same demo code.

Comment: i am displaying the result in recycler view. first time its blank when i go back and try for second time its working. i read that AsyncTask run in separate so that we wont get the result first time, is it true

Comment: @AseshaGeorge No, it's not true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149114/discussion-between-nitin-patel-and-asesha-george).

Answer (score 0):

```
private void event_load_data_from_server(int id){

    AsyncTask<Integer,Void,JSONArray> task = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, JSONArray>() {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                .url("http://api.zesteve.com/posteventlist.php?city="+ucl+"&eveid="+eveid+"&id="+integers[0])
                .build();

        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(Object... integers) {

            try {
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());
                return array;

            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                System.out.println("End of Catagory");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog.setMessage("Events Loading Wait...");
            showDialog();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray array) {
            for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){
                JSONObject object =array.getJSONObject(i);

                if(object.has("name")){
                    pname=object.getString("name");
                }else{
                    pname="";
                }
                if(object.has("timestamp")){
                    timestamp =object.getString("timestamp");
                }else{
                    timestamp="";
                }
                if(object.has("id")){
                    eveid=object.getInt("id");
                }else {
                    eveid=0;
                }
                if(object.has("address")){
                    address=object.getString("address");
                }else {
                    address="";
                }
                if(object.has("thumbnail")){
                    thumbnail=object.getString("thumbnail");
                }else {
                    thumbnail="";
                }

                EventPost events = new EventPost(pname, eveid, thumbnail,address,timestamp);

                eventPostList.add(events);
            }
            hideDialog();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
    task.execute(id);

}
```

Comment: i tried but is giving errors at integer in URL, object.getString("name")

Comment: Error:(95, 102) error: cannot find symbol variable integers

Comment: Error:(91, 45) error: incompatible types: <anonymous AsyncTask<Object,Object,JSONArray>> cannot be converted to AsyncTask<Integer,Void,Void>